# Is incremental EM a special case of SAGE?

Tags: expectation-maximization

I have come across "A View of the EM Algorithm that Justifies Incremental, Sparse, and Other Variants" [(Neal & Hinton, 1998)](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~radford/em.abstract.html). I was wondering if incremental update in EM as described here can be interpreted as a special case of space-alternating generalised expectation-maximization (SAGE) [(Fessler & Hero, 1994)](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~fessler/papers/files/jour/94/web/fessler-94-sag.pdf) as well?

More generally, I am interested in understanding if and how much these two algorithm formulations overlap? I am only familiar with SAGE among the two, which I worked with  about 12 years ago.